# lots of same values, how to leave only one of them

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table I've got category row. I'd like to know what categories do I have, without quering for all of them. Is there a way to make SQL query only return one occurence for lots of the sames?

Answer (score 3):

yes, use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT categoryName
FROM category
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbe4c/1)

Comment: Never knew about SQLFiddle, whoever is making these are awesome, awesome people. (referring to JSFiddle, SQLFiddle,etc if there are more)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp). It will only return each value once.